# C# XML deserialization issues / Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

it's me again.

I'm currently stuck at deserializing a specific XML file, which gives me headaches.

The XML that needs to be deserialized:

```
<AuditEntryData>
    <AuditEntryValue name="Supplier name" newValue="Assagne Corp." type="Text" />
    <AuditEntryValue name="MODDATETIME" oldValue="2021-09-15T17:07:37.0000000Z" newValue="2021-09-15T17:29:27.0000000Z" type="DateTime" />
    <AuditEntryTableValues>
        <T name="InvoiceItems">
            <Columns>
                <C name="Name" type="Text" />
                <C name="Accounting-Key" type="Text" />
                <C name="AdditionalColumn" type="Text" />
                <C name="Date" type="Date" />
                <C name="Value" type="Number" />
            </Columns>
            <OldValues>
                <R>
                    <C>Oh Long Johnson</C>
                    <C>23ufztg3u4ghf</C>
                    <C>Test33</C>
                    <C>2021-02-10T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>18.73</C>
                </R>
            </OldValues>
            <NewValues>
                <R>
                    <C>John Smith</C>
                    <C>23ufztg3u4ghf</C>
                    <C>Test33</C>
                    <C>2021-02-10T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>18.73</C>
                </R>
                <R>
                    <C>Johnathan Smith</C>
                    <C>eui5dctmcotgu</C>
                    <C>Test22</C>
                    <C>2021-09-15T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>13.12</C>
                </R>
            </NewValues>
        </T>
    </AuditEntryTableValues>
</AuditEntryData>
```

The class file generated with xsd:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class C {
    
    private string nameField;
    
    private string typeField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class R {
    
    private C[] cField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("C")]
    public C[] C {
        get {
            return this.cField;
        }
        set {
            this.cField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class AuditEntryData {
    
    private object[] itemsField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AuditEntryTableValues", typeof(AuditEntryDataAuditEntryTableValues), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AuditEntryValue", typeof(AuditEntryDataAuditEntryValue), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("C", typeof(C))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("R", typeof(R))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class AuditEntryDataAuditEntryTableValues {
    
    private AuditEntryDataAuditEntryTableValuesT[] tField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("T", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public AuditEntryDataAuditEntryTableValuesT[] T {
        get {
            return this.tField;
        }
        set {
            this.tField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class AuditEntryDataAuditEntryTableValuesT {
    
    private C[][] columnsField;
    
    private C[][][] oldValuesField;
    
    private C[][][] newValuesField;
    
    private string nameField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("C", typeof(C), IsNullable=false)]
    public C[][] Columns {
        get {
            return this.columnsField;
        }
        set {
            this.columnsField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("R", typeof(C[]), IsNullable=false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("C", typeof(C), IsNullable=false, NestingLevel=1)]
    public C[][][] OldValues {
        get {
            return this.oldValuesField;
        }
        set {
            this.oldValuesField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("R", typeof(C[]), IsNullable=false)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("C", typeof(C), IsNullable=false, NestingLevel=1)]
    public C[][][] NewValues {
        get {
            return this.newValuesField;
        }
        set {
            this.newValuesField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class AuditEntryDataAuditEntryValue {
    
    private string nameField;
    
    private string newValueField;
    
    private string typeField;
    
    private string oldValueField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string newValue {
        get {
            return this.newValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.newValueField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type {
        get {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string oldValue {
        get {
            return this.oldValueField;
        }
        set {
            this.oldValueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Deserializing the xml gives me the following error:

Multi dimensional arrays:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'C[]' to 'C'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'C[][]' to 'C[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'C' to 'C[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'C[]' to 'C[][]
```

Single dimensional arrays (after modifying the class file):

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'C' to 'C[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'C[]' to 'C'
```

The xml is produced by an external program, so I have no control over it. Changing the format therefore is not possible.
If I remove/comment out the type attribute declarations, I am able to load the XML, but it won't load the **OldValues** and **NewValues**.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILE = @"c:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILE);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AuditEntryData));
            AuditEntryData auditEntryData = (AuditEntryData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    public class AuditEntryData
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public AuditEntryValue[] AuditEntryValue { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("AuditEntryTableValues")]
        [XmlArrayItem("T")]
        public AuditEntryTableValue[] AuditEntryTableValue { get; set; }
    }
    public class AuditEntryValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string newValue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string oldValue { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string type { get; set; }

    }
    public class AuditEntryTableValue
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Columns")]
        [XmlArrayItem("C")]
        public Column[] Columns { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("OldValues")]
        [XmlArrayItem("R")]
        public OldValue[] OldValues { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("NewValues")]
        [XmlArrayItem("R")]
        public NewValue[] NewValues { get; set; }
    }
    public class Column
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
    public class OldValue
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string[] C{ get; set; }
    }
    public class NewValue
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string[] C { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're a life saver. This wasn't the first time stumbling on this, but I didn't remember how to fix it the last time. I probably ended up doing it manually, like you did.
My sincere thanks for this.

Is there a way to make xsd more reliable when it comes to XML data like in the op?

Comment: It is not the xsd.  The issue is the xml and schema do not match.  XML files should always be validated when generated against the schema.  I've seen too many cases where people get xml files that do not match schema and have to contact the people who generated the xml to fix the issues.

Comment: That schema was generated from that file with xsd. Technically xsd produced this "garbage". In most cases it does work without a hassle, but in this specific case (or another I had in the past) it didn't work out that well, when creating the shema with xsd.

Comment: XML to schema does not work as well as schema to xml.  The larger the xml file you use to create schema the better results you get.  A tool that convert xml to schema does not know type(s), or arrays.  Has to do a lot of guessing.  Creating Schema from requirements works much better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working simplified example.
Just use `XML.Run()`.
Probably OldValues and NewValues class may be merged into one class only, by specifying the `ElementName`.

```
public class XML
    {
        private readonly string xml = @"
<AuditEntryData>
    <AuditEntryValue name=""Supplier name"" newValue=""Assagne Corp."" type=""Text"" />
    <AuditEntryValue name=""MODDATETIME"" oldValue=""2021-09-15T17:07:37.0000000Z"" newValue=""2021-09-15T17:29:27.0000000Z"" type=""DateTime"" />
    <AuditEntryTableValues>
        <T name=""InvoiceItems"">
            <Columns>
                <C name=""Name"" type=""Text"" />
                <C name=""Accounting-Key"" type=""Text"" />
                <C name=""AdditionalColumn"" type=""Text"" />
                <C name=""Date"" type=""Date"" />
                <C name=""Value"" type=""Number"" />
            </Columns>
            <OldValues>
                <R>
                    <C>Oh Long Johnson</C>
                    <C>23ufztg3u4ghf</C>
                    <C>Test33</C>
                    <C>2021-02-10T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>18.73</C>
                </R>
            </OldValues>
            <NewValues>
                <R>
                    <C>John Smith</C>
                    <C>23ufztg3u4ghf</C>
                    <C>Test33</C>
                    <C>2021-02-10T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>18.73</C>
                </R>
                <R>
                    <C>Johnathan Smith</C>
                    <C>eui5dctmcotgu</C>
                    <C>Test22</C>
                    <C>2021-09-15T00:00:00.0000000Z</C>
                    <C>13.12</C>
                </R>
            </NewValues>
        </T>
    </AuditEntryTableValues>
</AuditEntryData>
";

        public void Run()
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(xml);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AuditEntryData));
            var o = (AuditEntryData)ser.Deserialize(stream);

        }

        [XmlRoot]
        public class AuditEntryData
        {
            [XmlElement("AuditEntryValue")]
            public List<AuditEntryValue> AuditEntryValues { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public AuditEntryTableValues AuditEntryTableValues { get; set; }

        }

        public class AuditEntryValue
        {
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string name { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string oldValue { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string newValue { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class AuditEntryTableValues
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public T T { get; set; }
        }

        public class T
        {
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public Columns Columns { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public OldValues OldValues { get; set; }

            [XmlElement]
            public NewValues NewValues { get; set; }
        }

        public class Columns
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "C", Type = typeof(C))]
            public List<C> Cs { get; set; }
        }


        public class C
        {
            [XmlAttribute]
            public string name { get; set; }

            [XmlAttribute]
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class OldValues
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public R R { get; set; }
        }

        public class NewValues
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public R R { get; set; }
        }

        public class R
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "C")]
            public List<string> Cs { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your addition. It produces slightly more nesting in the resulting JSON, so I'll stick with @jdweng approach.